# When to use rerender vs unmount and mount with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Looking through the API of React Testing Library, I see that there's a [rerender](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/) function. The documents say

> It'd probably be better if you test the component that's doing the prop updating to ensure that the props are being updated correctly (see the Guiding Principles section). That said, if you'd prefer to update the props of a rendered component in your test, this function can be used to update props of the rendered component.

If I'm trying to test that a component renders differently after it has been unmounted and remounted. Is there any reason to not use rerender instead of calling `unmount` and `render` again?

So far, I've tried looking up other options, but haven't seen any definitive differences between the rerender and unmount+render method.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`rerender`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/1c67477443244e52c3ae57db49e1a6e8226e0c0d/src/pure.js#L160) source code, we know it will reuse the `container`, `baseElement` and `root` options render the UI.

For example, we can pass the `container` HTML element to `render` function.

You don't need to pass the `container` anymore to the `rerender` function for the following renders(test case 1).

If you use `render`, you should always pass the `container` option to it(test case 2). Otherwise, it will throw an warning(test case 3).

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tbody> cannot appear as a child of <div>
```

You don't need to call `unmount` in every test case unless you want to test the code after the component unmounts, because RTL will use the [cleanup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#skipping-auto-cleanup) function by default to help you clean up the rendered component.

The following example compares `render` and `rerender`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const TestComp = ({ donuts }: { donuts: string }) => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Donuts</th>
        <td>{donuts}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  );
};

describe('76157953', () => {
  test('rerender', () => {
    const $table = document.createElement('table');
    $table.id = 'test';
    document.body.appendChild($table);
    const { rerender, container } = render(<TestComp donuts="3,000" />, {
      container: document.body.appendChild($table),
    });
    expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<table
  id="test"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th
        scope="row"
      >
        Donuts
      </th>
      <td>
        3,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
`);
    rerender(<TestComp donuts="2,000" />);
    expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<table
  id="test"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th
        scope="row"
      >
        Donuts
      </th>
      <td>
        2,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
`);
  });

  test('render', () => {
    const $table = document.createElement('table');
    $table.id = 'test';
    document.body.appendChild($table);
    const result1 = render(<TestComp donuts="3,000" />, { container: $table });
    expect(result1.container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<table
  id="test"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th
        scope="row"
      >
        Donuts
      </th>
      <td>
        3,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
`);
    const result2 = render(<TestComp donuts="2,000" />, { container: $table });
    expect(result2.container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<table
  id="test"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th
        scope="row"
      >
        Donuts
      </th>
      <td>
        2,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
`);
  });

  test('render without container', () => {
    const $table = document.createElement('table');
    $table.id = 'test';
    document.body.appendChild($table);
    const result1 = render(<TestComp donuts="3,000" />, { container: $table });
    expect(result1.container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<table
  id="test"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th
        scope="row"
      >
        Donuts
      </th>
      <td>
        3,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
`);
    const result2 = render(<TestComp donuts="2,000" />);
    expect(result2.container.firstChild?.nodeName.toLocaleLowerCase()).not.toBe('table');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  console.error
    Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tbody> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
        at tbody
        at donuts (/home/lindu/workspace/mrdulin/jest-v29-codelab/stackoverflow/76157953/index.test.tsx:4:21)

      127 | </table>
      128 | `);
    > 129 |     const result2 = render(<TestComp donuts="2,000" />);
          |                           ^
      130 |     expect(result2.container.firstChild?.nodeName.toLocaleLowerCase()).not.toBe('table');
      131 |   });
      132 | });

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:86:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/76157953/index.test.tsx:129:27)

 PASS  stackoverflow/76157953/index.test.tsx
  76157953
    ✓ rerender (16 ms)
    ✓ render (3 ms)
    ✓ render without container (24 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   5 passed, 5 total
Time:        0.652 s, estimated 1 s
```

package version:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2"
```